# FB LIke Button & FBML

Tags: fbml

I have created a tab (now in the side menu) using FBML which links to my website. I have added a "Share" button which works, but can't seem to add a "Like" Button. Can anyone tell me the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't officially... However there is a workaround in using the FBML comments like button.
See: http://blog.elliotjameschong.com/2011/01/03/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-to-a-fbml-tab/

Answer (score 0):

watch this, is in spanish but the code works
http://cosasparaelface.blogspot.com/2011/01/colocar-el-boton-me-gusta-en-pagina.html